# How to display user added text in Tree format

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have added input/textarea tag in my enter image description hereform html where user can add multiple keywords in it .. 
1) I am not sure how to add  close button to user text and display it in text area(below is the screen shot)[image].
2) And i also want to add the tree view for the submitted form with data with button and user can edit the data if he wants(see tree screenshot for the same[image]..

```
            code:
html:
            <div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bar">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-up"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-down"></i>Keywords
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">

    <div class="collapse" id="bar">
    <ul>
            <li><button onclick="myFunction()">+ Add Keyword</button></li>
      <li>


        <div id="myDIV">
    <form>Keyword<br/><br>
        <input type="text" value="" id="keywordname" name="name">
        </input>


    </form>
    <button onclick="saveFunction2()">Save </button>

</div>




      </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="panel panel-info">
  <div class="panel-heading collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bar">
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-up"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-fw fa-chevron-down"></i>others
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
    <!-- The inside div eliminates the 'jumping' animation. -->
    <div class="collapse" id="bar">
      <button onclick="myFunction()">+ Add Keyword</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

CSS:
.panel-heading.collapsed .fa-chevron-up,
.panel-heading .fa-chevron-down {
  display: none;
}

.panel-heading.collapsed .fa-chevron-down,
.panel-heading .fa-chevron-up {
  display: inline-block;
}

i.fa {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

.collapsed ~ .panel-body {
  padding: 0;
}
ul, li { list-style: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
ul { padding-left: 1em; }
li { padding-left: 1em;
  border: 1px dotted black;
  border-width: 0 0 1px 1px; 
}
li.container { border-bottom: 0px; }
li.empty { font-style: italic;
  color: silver;
  border-color: silver;
}
li p { margin: 0;
  background: white;
  position: relative;
  top: 0.5em; 
}
li ul { 
  border-top: 1px dotted black; 
  margin-left: -1em;     
  padding-left: 2em; 
}
ul li:last-child ul {
  border-left: 1px solid white;
  margin-left: -17px;
}

#myDIV {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Please let me how to achieve above 2 things, thanks in advance for your suggestions.

Comment: Hi, could you add what you've already tried ?

Comment: please use below link to c the code 
https://jsfiddle.net/2pLtj8sn/

Comment: You could use a snippet to add this directly into your question. ( Ctrl + M )

Comment: @Nicolas,added the link

Comment: No, use the snippet to copy the code from jsfiddle to your question directly. Have you read the [ask] section ?

Comment: hi all, any suggestions?

Comment: hi all, any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

**index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"></style>
    <body>
        <div ng-app="treeApp"  ng-controller="treeController">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <div id="accordion">
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header bg-info" id="headingOne">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                    <button class="btn text-light" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Keywords" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                                        Keywords 
                                    </button>
                                </h5>
                                </div>

                                <div id="Keywords" class="collapse show" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                        <ul>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="t input-group">
                                                    <input list="companiesList" class="form-control form-per" placeholder="Company Name" aria-describedby="inputGroupPrepend" ng-model="selectedCompany">
                                                    <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                                        <span class="input-group-text fa fa-close" id="inputGroupPrepend">  </span>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <datalist id="companiesList">
                                                        <option ng-repeat="c in companies" >{{ c }}</option>
                                                    </datalist>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                                <div class="t input-group">
                                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Keyword" ng-model="newKeyword">
                                                    <button ng-click="addKeyword(selectedCompany)" class="btn btn-primary" ng-disabled="!newKeyword || !selectedCompany">
                                                        <span class="fa fa-plus"></span> Add Keyword</button>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>

                                            <li>
                                                <div class="t keywordsList">
                                                    <span class="keyword-box" ng-repeat="k in keywordTree[selectedCompany]">
                                                        {{ k }} <i class="fa fa-close" ng-click="removeTag(k, selectedCompany)"></i>
                                                    </span>
                                                </div>
                                            </li>

                                        <ul>
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="card">
                                <div class="card-header bg-info" id="headingTwo">
                                <h5 class="mb-0">
                                    <button class="btn text-light" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Others" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
                                    Others
                                    </button>
                                </h5>
                                </div>
                                <div id="Others" class="collapse" aria-labelledby="headingTwo" data-parent="#accordion">
                                <div class="card-body">
                                    Anim pariatur cliche reprehenderit, enim eiusmod high life accusamus terry richardson ad squid. 3 wolf moon officia aute, non cupidatat skateboard dolor brunch. Food truck quinoa nesciunt laborum eiusmod. Brunch 3 wolf moon tempor, sunt aliqua put a bird on it squid single-origin coffee nulla assumenda shoreditch et. Nihil anim keffiyeh helvetica, craft beer labore wes anderson cred nesciunt sapiente ea proident. Ad vegan excepteur butcher vice lomo. Leggings occaecat craft beer farm-to-table, raw denim aesthetic synth nesciunt you probably haven't heard of them accusamus labore sustainable VHS.
                                </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>  
    <script>
    var app = angular.module('treeApp', []);

    app.controller('treeController', function($scope) {
        $scope.companies = [ 
            'Apple',
            'Microsoft',
            'Google',
            'IBM',
        ];

        $scope.keywordTree = {};
        $scope.companies.forEach(function(c){
            $scope.keywordTree[c] = []; 
        })
        $scope.addKeyword = function(sc){
            if($scope.keywordTree[sc].includes($scope.newKeyword)){
                alert("This keyword already exists")
            }else{

                $scope.keywordTree[sc].push($scope.newKeyword);
            }
            $scope.newKeyword = '';
        }
        $scope.removeTag = function(t , sc){
            alert('are you sre you want to remove ' + t + 'from list 
             ')
            var idx = $scope.keywordTree[sc].indexOf(t);
            $scope.keywordTree[sc].splice(t, 1);
        }

    });
    </script>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**style.css**

```
    code,
    kbd,
    pre,
    .col-12,
    .card,
    .card-header,
    #accordion,
    .img-rounded,
    .img-thumbnail,
    .img-circle,
    .form-control,
    .btn,
    .btn-link,
    .dropdown-menu,
    .list-group-item,
    .input-group-addon,
    .input-group-btn,
    .nav-tabs a,
    .nav-pills a,
    .navbar,
    .navbar-toggle,
    .icon-bar,
    .breadcrumb,
    .pagination,
    .pager *,
    .label,
    .badge,
    .jumbotron,
    .thumbnail,
    .alert,
    .progress,
    .panel,
    .well,
    .modal-content,
    .tooltip-inner,
    .popover,
    .popover-title,
    .carousel-indicators li {
        border-radius:0 !important;
    }
    .panel-heading.collapsed .fa-chevron-up,
    .panel-heading .fa-chevron-down {
    display: none;
    }

    .panel-heading.collapsed .fa-chevron-down,
    .panel-heading .fa-chevron-up {
    display: inline-block;
    }

    i.fa {
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 5px;
    }
    .form-per{
        background-color: #e9ecef !important;
        border-right : none
    }
    .form-per::placeholder::before{
        contain: '*';
        /* color: red; */
    }
    .input-group-text{
        border-left: none;
    }
    .card-body{
        padding-top: 0;
    }
    .collapsed{
        left: 20px;
    }
    li{
        padding-top: 10px;
    }
    ul, li { list-style: none; }

    .t:before {
        content: '----';
        margin-left: -20px;
        /* margin-right: 10px; */
    }

    ul { 
        padding-left: 20px; 
        border-left: 1px dashed black;
    }

    ul  { 
        padding-left: 20px; 
        border-left: 1px dashed black;
    }
    ul  { 
        border-left: 1px dashed black;
    }



    .keywordsList {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 3px;
    border: 1px dashed black
    }

    .keyword-box{
        border: 1px solid black;
        padding: 2px;
        margin: 5px;
    }
```

Let me know this is what you are looking for?

Comment: thanks for your replay.. its not matching exactly but got an idea how to customize according to my requirement for tree view..
I am not sure how to add close button to user text and display it in text area(above is the screen shot)

Comment: Kindly check updated code for removing item from the list